# Clean wordpress spam links

Tags: wordpress, xss

I have a wordpress 5.0 site and few days ago, Google Ads detected malicious links inside my website. They are like this:

```
*http://apps9244.ittprize60.live/?utm_medium=oxxGrJ1EO8rl%2FlkgHhDHtdaJe%2B6y3ml38Z%2B1ZX9QaLo%3D&t=main7_5*
```

I tried to scan it dozens of times finding them inside the wordpress files but I am unable to find anything. I tried to do a mysqldump to see better the database and I found an INSERT INTO inside wp_options table.

But this INSERT INTO is done automatically and I am unable to find where it does something like this.

Anyone knows how to find those links? Thank you very much.

Comment: Every mysqldump will have a insert into.. wp_options table. Can you be more specific why it looks suspicious? And what files changed recently? That may tell where...

Comment: Yep, finally I found a solution. Sorry for the delay this thing took me a lot of time. I'll explain may solution in this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [NoBugs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778234/nobugs) I found the problem. First I did a mysqldump of my database. Then I started a search using **grep**:

```
sudo grep -rl "apps9244" /directory/to/website/
```

I tried different strings like "prize", "ittprize". Fortunately I found an INSERT INTO with the same string. This was the proof about the malware.

Finally I tried this:

1. Remove old theme and install the updated one.
2. Update all plugins.
3. Check .htaccess file and Wordpress main files.
4. Ask for a manual revision to Google Ads Support.

This thing took me around 8 days to be solved. I think could help to other people.